# FB API App-scoped user id forbids event invitation

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-events

On an FB application (created before April 30 2014), users to our website are given the choice of picking friends to invite to an event they create. The website is using the JS SDK v1.0.

The user ids being returned to the visitor trying out the tool are now app-scoped, instead of the former global ids pre-2.0. When such app-scoped uids are used against the `/{event-id}/invited` users endpoint, a response of `true` is passed to the callback, *but the invite never reaches the target friend*. Performing the same request using the former (global, pre-2.0) uid allows the invitation flow to reach its destination (and is reflected on the event page).

Additional information is that the very code for this functionality is being used with a different app id. Every other aspect of the functionality, namely listing friends, creating events, reading an users' events, and sharing on the wall work normally - our issue remains with inviting the users to an event with the returned app-scoped ids.

Has anyone faced this same issue or has any insight that can be of use?

**Edit:**
One extra piece of information is that our application is also using XMPP for sending chat messages - this is also failing due to the app-scoped ids.

Comment: The ability to fetch a user's friends doesn't exist in 2.0 and neither does the ability to invite friends to a list - i suspect this is probably working as intended - it makes sense that users who authorise the app using v2.0 (i.e for whom you get an app scoped ID) aren't invitable via the API

Comment: Negative. Users are authorizing the application via SDK 1.0, as I mentioned on the question. We're not migrating to 2.0 as support for event creation has been deprecated

Comment: Then where are you getting the app scoped IDs? v1.0 apps should still  get a canonical ID unless they're using v2.0 of the Oauth/login dialog (or to put it another way, users logging into your app with v1.0 will get the 'original' ID, users logging in with v2.0 or later will get app scoped IDs)

Comment: Migration to 2.0 requires a change on the JS library being used (from all.js to sdk.js), which we haven't applied. However, **will Admins, Developers and Testers automatically be assigned app-scoped (v2.0) ids once given a role to the app**?

Comment: Users logging into your app with v1.0 will get the 'original' ID, users logging in with v2.0 or later will get app scoped IDs - this is based on which version of the oauth dialog that user users to grant your app permissions

Comment: The answer to that is v1.0. My question on the comment above seems relevant.

Comment: Being an admin, developer, etc, shouldn't affect the ID returned - that should be based only on which version of the login dialog was used to grant permissions, as far as i know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here - one that the application, though created before Aug 15 2014, was using API 2.0, and that the functionality I was looking for (xmpp_login), was no longer supported. We have pivoted away from this approach and are getting ready for the rewrite the new API is pushing.